# TouchableOpacity/TouchableHighlight delay before starting function in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I have a problem with these two component in React-Native, when click on it the function seems to start with the delay of 1-2 seconds

```
const ExampleComponent = (props) => {

  const _asyncFunction = async() => {
   props.startLoading() // dispatch an action
   const response = await promise();
   props.stopLoading();
   props.goToAnotherRoute(response);
  }

  return(
   <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => {_asyncFunction()}}>
      <Text>click on me</Text>
   </TouchableHighlight>
  )
}
```

Comment: Well, it might be because the function you are executing is an asynchronous function?

Comment: @seulgibearok but the spinner, invoked by startLoading rendering always after 1-2 seconds :(